# UIWebView does not show an escaped unicode symbol

Tags: html, ios, unicode, uiwebview

My application downloading some html code and showing it in UIWebView
The problem I have at the moment is that the UIWebView can't show unicode symbols which presented with HTML escaped index:

```
NSString *html = @"<head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body>&#x1D540;<body>";
[_wv loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

After this all I have is an empty square symbol instead of  (MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL I)
What should I do to handle this problem?

UPD
looks like I met with unsupported symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems uiwebview doesn't support some unicode chars.